How to open a file outside default function in k6
I have to read a 5k row csv file containing image data like filename, filesize, filepath,filehash and have to upload images using an upload file API. I created a script but due to a restriction of K6 that file should be opened in the init context. We are not able to place the load. Need help here

I'm not sure I understand. Which problem do you face loading the file in the init context and then using it in your function?

Without any example code is difficult to help. I suggest you construct a SharedArray in the init context.
